# How can I predict a rotation as quaternion using angular velocities?

Tags: rotations, quaternions, kinematics, kalman-filter

I want to generate a rotation and the corresponding angular velocity in 3-d space in order to test a Kalman filter, but converting and applying these angular velocities as quaternions gives me wrong results compared to just applying an angular velocity to an angular rotation.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Here is my approach:

Let's assume we have

$f(t) = \sin(t)$

$dx f(t) = \cos(t)$

I have a rotation and an angular velocity for the 3-axes

$\phi(t) = [x\;y\;z]; \;\omega(t) = [x\;y\;z]$.

The rotation is given given by

$\phi(t) = [f(t)\;f(t+1)\;f(t+2)]$,

and the angular velocity by

$\omega(t) = [dx f(t)\;dx f(t+1)\;dx f(t+2)]$.

For the measurement step we have:

$\phi(t) = \phi(t)$

$q(t) = \text{RotationVectorToQuat}(\phi(t)) $

For each prediction step the new rotation is given by:

$dt = t - t_{-1}$

$\phi(t) = \phi (t-1) * \omega(t) * dt$

$q(t) = q(t-1) \otimes \text{RotationVectorToQuat}(\omega(t)*dt) $

RotationVectorToQuat is given by

$\text{angle} = \text{norm}(\phi)$

$\text{halfAngle} = \text{angle}/2$

$q = [\cos(\text{halfAngle})\; (\phi/\text{angle} * \sin(\text{halfAngle}))]$

Here is the resulting plot, as you can see the quaternion result converted back to a rotation vector drifts during the prediction.

[image: X axis Plot]

You can checkout my matlab demo here: https://drive.proton.me/urls/GVZHW21W78#XGKYTgCbc84f

Comment: Can you explain your plots some more? It's not entirely clear to me what I'm looking at or what you expect it to look like.

Comment: I don't know if you use it anywhere, but your update to $\phi$ makes no sense to me (I assume it's a component-wise product). The best you can do I think is just derive $\phi(t)$ directly from $q(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is... not right. You cannot just turn $\omega(t)\,dt$ into a rotation quaternion and expect to get the correct update to $q$.

The quaternion $q$ defines the motion of a particle with position vector $r$ (represented as an imaginary quaternion) via
$$
  r(t) = q(t)r(0)\bar q(t)
$$
where $\bar q$ is the conjugate and we've assumed that $q$ is normalized. Here we are using juxtaposition for quaternion multiplication. The angular velocity is defined by
$$
  \dot r(t) = r(t)\times\omega(t)
$$
with $\dot r$ the time derivative and $\times$ corresponding to the vector cross product, though it can be written algebraically using the quaternion product as
$$
  A\times B = \frac12(AB - BA).
$$
What you'll find by differentiating the first equation with $r$ and $q$ (and by some other shennanigans) is
$$
  \dot q(t) = \frac12\omega(t)q(t).
$$
That is to say that the update equation for $q$ must be
$$
  \frac{q(t) - q(t - dt)}{dt} = \frac12\omega(t)q(t) \implies \left(1-\frac12\omega(t)\,dt\right)q(t) = q(t-dt)
$$$$
\implies q(t) = \left(1-\frac12\omega(t)\,dt\right)^{-1}q(t-dt).
$$
Since $\omega$ is pure imaginary we can write
$$
  q(t) = \frac{1+\frac12\omega(t)\,dt}{1 + \frac14|\omega(t)|^2}q(t-dt),
$$
though it would be best to just compute
$$
  \left(1 + \frac12\omega(t)\,dt\right)q(t-dt)
$$
and then normalize. Remember that these are *quaternion* products. Note also that $\phi$ is unecessary except maybe to specify the inital orientation.

---

A possible reference is section 3.4.1 of *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* by Chris Doran and Anthony Lasenby, though this is a book employing [geometric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra) and not just quaternions. This particular topic is expressible using just quaternions though, and so I've adapted the content there slightly.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, first off thank you for your time and feedback. 

My rotations are around the origin. 

According to this: 

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.02508.pdf

[4.6.1 Zeroth order integration]

The time integration of a quaternion is given by 

$q_{t} = q_t \otimes q\{\omega_{t-1} * \Delta t\}$

where 

$q\{\omega\} = \text{RotationVectorToQuat(\omega)}$

I don't understand your end result, the term

$(1 + 1/2 \omega(t) dt)$ is not a quaternion.

Comment: @discipulus I am also just working with rotations around the origin. Here I am treating $\omega$ as an imaginary quaternion $\omega_xi + \omega_yj + \omega_xk$. I will look at your reference and get back to you; I'm confident in what I wrote but maybe I don't understand your situatuion and it doesn't apply.

Comment: @discipulus It's clear to me that they are also treating $\omega$ as a quaternion in the paper you reference.

Comment: I understand now that we're making the assumption that $\omega$ is constant on the interval $[t - dt, t]$; in this case your equation is correct. The equation I wrote is a first-order integration of $q$ which works for any $\omega$, whereas your equation is exact in the case that $\omega$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you again for you feedback, even for my simulated data the angular velocity is not really constant but I assume it is, for simplicity. 
- 
I am trying to implement the error-state Kalman filter from the referenced paper but I have horrible drifts. I have to use quaternions and so I simply try to analyze the problem with simulated data and I started to analyze the integration of the angular velocity with this simulation.

Comment: The problem that I have is that by just using angular velocities and applying them to the rotation vector I get very good results, doing the same with quaternions give me drifts and I don't understand why. Maybe I have already made some wrong assumptions about the rotation, angular velocities and how they relate to quaternions.

Comment: I looked into your solution, but I am not sure how to apply it. I did some research and your solution looks like this one

https://mariogc.com/post/angular-velocity-quaternions/ 

[Quaternion Integration]

Applying this to my matlab demo gives me horrible wrong results though. 

But since you said my solution should also work, I am still left with why do I get drifts with quaternions, what am I missing here :) ?

Comment: One more thing if I set the axis y and z to zero for rotations and angular velocities, the resulting quaternion converted back to a rotation vector equals the result of just applying the angular velocity * dt to the angular rotation. Maybe my generated data is wrong ?

Comment: @discipulus I should definitely mention that it looks like my quantities are conjugated relative to your reference. So in my expressions above you should use $\bar q$ and $\bar\omega$ instead of $q$ and $\omega$.

Comment: "...if I set the axis y and z to zero..." This sounds right to me? In this case you just have a rotation around the $x$-axis and the rotation angle evolves as $|\phi(t)| = |\phi(t-dt)| + |\omega|dt$